# Prevent Hibernate from converting Instant to Local time before inserting to DB

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, java-8

I got a Spring Boot project and I want to save an Java Object with an Instant variable to my MSSQL DB with JPA and hibernate. The time is in UTC (as it is an Instant) but it seems that hiberate converts the time to local time before inserting it to my DB.

The value I want to save: "2018-11-20T08:34:33.965Z"

the value as saved in the DB: "2018-11-20T09:34:33.965" as the local time in the DB is UTC+1.

My Entity looks something like that:

```
@Entity(name = "MyEntity")
public class MyEntity {

private Instant myTime;
}
```

my repo:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String>{}
dependencies in build.gradle
```

my dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.1.12.RELEASE")
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.0.12.Final')
```

How can I get hibernate to just save the time with converting it?

If you require any further information, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell hibernate to use UTC as default timezone using following property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```